# add decimal places to number in a report

Tags: ms-access, report, ms-access-2007

I have a number in a table like so **153695029**, I need to format it to **1,536,950.29**.  I have used the ~format and decimal~ spot for textbox and I get **153,695,029.00**.  What am I doing wrong?  The datatype is a double.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set the Format of the TextBox control, to do this. Something like,

```
? Format(153695029, "###,###,###,###,###.00")
  153,695,029.00
```